# Using Json.net to deserialize Json with some changing object names

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net

I'm new here so thanks for the great content; invaluable stuff.

I'm deserializing some Json from TDAmeritrade into a C# desktop app using the "Option Chain" api.

Depending on the input to the api, I can get a response with multiple expiration dates, multiple strike prices, and multiple option objects.

Here's a link to a typical response: [API ResponseTDAmeritrade Json Example](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1X5gnz2x1xfZz8L_yKUTeNe_pKY7KrZHL/view?usp=sharing)

A snippet of the problem code:

```js
"numberOfContracts": 8,
  "putExpDateMap": {

    **"2020-08-21:50": {
      "15.0":** [

        {
          "putCall": "PUT",
          "symbol": "FMCI_082120P15",
          "description": "FMCI Aug 21 2020 15 Put",
          "exchangeName": "OPR",
```

The problem is that the dates and strike prices change in each response. I've learned that I can deserialize into a "Dictionary<string, List<Type> listName" so I did that in the OptionChain and ExpDate classes but still can't get it working.

Here is the current error: [error trace](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zcml_qG31u4nrMkRfhvrScsQKBRJMjZo/view?usp=sharing)

Here are my classes, created from json2csharp.com but with the date and strike price classes modified:

```
 class OptionChain
{
    public string symbol { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public Underlying underlying { get; set; }
    public string strategy { get; set; }
    public double interval { get; set; }
    public bool isDelayed { get; set; }
    public bool isIndex { get; set; }
    public double interestRate { get; set; }
    public double underlyingPrice { get; set; }
    public double volatility { get; set; }
    public double daysToExpiration { get; set; }
    public int numberOfContracts { get; set; }   
    public Dictionary<string, List<expDate>> putExpDateMap { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, List<expDate>> callExpDateMap { get; set; }

public class expDate
{
    public Dictionary<string, List<StrikePrice>> strikePrices { get; set; }
}

public class StrikePrice
{
    public Option[] options { get; set; }
}

public class Option
{
    public string putCall { get; set; }
    public string symbol { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string exchangeName { get; set; }
    public double bid { get; set; }
    public double ask { get; set; }
    public double last { get; set; }
    public double mark { get; set; }
    public int bidSize { get; set; }
    public int askSize { get; set; }
    public string bidAskSize { get; set; }
    public int lastSize { get; set; }
    public double highPrice { get; set; }
    public double lowPrice { get; set; }
    public double openPrice { get; set; }
    public double closePrice { get; set; }
    public int totalVolume { get; set; }
    public object tradeDate { get; set; }
    public long tradeTimeInLong { get; set; }
    public long quoteTimeInLong { get; set; }
    public double netChange { get; set; }
    public double volatility { get; set; }
    public double delta { get; set; }
    public double gamma { get; set; }
    public double theta { get; set; }
    public double vega { get; set; }
    public double rho { get; set; }
    public int openInterest { get; set; }
    public double timeValue { get; set; }
    public double theoreticalOptionValue { get; set; }
    public double theoreticalVolatility { get; set; }
    public  OptionDeliverablesList optionDeliverablesList { get; set; }
    public double strikePrice { get; set; }
    public long expirationDate { get; set; }
    public int daysToExpiration { get; set; }
    public string expirationType { get; set; }
    public long lastTradingDay { get; set; }
    public double multiplier { get; set; }
    public string settlementType { get; set; }
    public string deliverableNote { get; set; }
    public bool isIndexOption { get; set; }
    public double percentChange { get; set; }
    public double markChange { get; set; }
    public double markPercentChange { get; set; }
    public bool inTheMoney { get; set; }
    public bool mini { get; set; }
    public bool nonStandard { get; set; }

 public class OptionDeliverablesList
{
    public string symbol { get; set; }
    public string assetType { get; set; }
    public double deliverableUnits { get; set; }
    public string currencyType { get; set; }
}
```

Am I doing something wrong in the Dictionaries? The way I understand it from my many hours of reading, the expiration dates and strike prices need to be read anonymously.

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Forgot to mention my deserialization code: OptionChain chain = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OptionChain>(chainObject.ToString()

Comment: JSON sample snippet looks a bit confusing because of partial sample and c# POCO is very big and looks like it contains properies going beyond the scope of current problem. Maybe removing excessive stuff from question will make it easier to understand. If I get your problem right - you have probelms deserializing json structure where keys are dynamic values but not static property names, correct? e.g. {"putExpDateMap" : { "2020-08-05 21:50" : {"10" : {}, "11" : {} }, "2019-03-06 14:50" : {...}}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get your problem right - you have probelms deserializing json structure where keys are dynamic values but not static property names, correct? If so- you have modeled incorrect POCO (there are two nested  dictionaries).
POCOs below give correct deserialization results (rest of properties skipped)

```
class OptionChain
{
    public string Symbol { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, ExpDate[]>> PutExpDateMap { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, ExpDate[]>> CallExpDateMap { get; set; }
    //other properties ignored because dont matter
}

class ExpDate
{
    public string ExchangeName { get; set; }
    public decimal Bid { get; set; }
    public decimal Ask { get; set; }
    //other properties ignored because dont matter
}
```

Tested POCOs with json sample provided in your post:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var t = File.ReadAllText("test.json");
        var r = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OptionChain>(t);
        Console.WriteLine($"Total elements in {nameof(r.PutExpDateMap)} : {r.PutExpDateMap.Count()}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Keys in {nameof(r.PutExpDateMap)} : {string.Join(",", r.PutExpDateMap.Keys)}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Total elements in {nameof(r.CallExpDateMap)} : {r.CallExpDateMap.Count()}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Keys in {nameof(r.CallExpDateMap)} : {string.Join(",", r.CallExpDateMap.Keys)}");
    }
```

Application output is:

[image]

Comment: The nested Dictionaries was the trick. Thanks so much!

Comment: Nice job @n.prokhorov!